# Find Documentation of Rust Prelude type

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using the below code to open a file reference as per [Tutorial](https://github.com/mehcode/config-rs/blob/2c0b201055be60ec45e258adcc6c4b6e01bcd627/examples/hierarchical-env/src/settings.rs#L50)

```
File::with_name(&format!("config/{}", env)
```

Where will I find the documentation of this `with_name` function of the file.
Despite googling I couldn't find it

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the file you linked you can see that `File` is not `std::fs::File`, but imported from the `config` crate. Here is its documentation: https://docs.rs/config/0.10.1/config/struct.File.html